# Failed to install WWW::HtmlUnit in Windows box

Tags: java, perl, classpath, htmlunit

I'm trying to install [WWW::HTMLUnit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-HtmlUnit/) on Windows 7. There're step that I run through:

1. Install Inline::Java 0.53
2. Install WWW::HTMLUnit 0.15

At step 2, after nmake, I type nmake test to test module but it failed. Here's output:

```
C:\nmake test

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00_basic...........
t/00_basic...........NOK 1/1#   Failed test 'use WWW::HtmlUnit;'
#   at t/00_basic.t line 9.
#     Tried to use 'WWW::HtmlUnit'.
#     Error:  Class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient not found at C:/Perl/site/lib/Inline/Java.pm line 619
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2, <GEN7> line 4.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
t/00_basic...........dubious
        Test returned status 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
DIED. FAILED test 1
        Failed 1/1 tests, 0.00% okay
t/01_hello...........Class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient not found at C:/Perl/site/lib/Inline/Java.pm line 619
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/01_hello.t line 4, <GEN7> line 4.
t/01_hello...........dubious
        Test returned status 26 (wstat 6656, 0x1a00)
t/02_hello_sweet.....dubious
        Test returned status 19 (wstat 4864, 0x1300)
t/03_clickhandler....Class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient not found at C:/Perl/site/lib/Inline/Java.pm line 619
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/03_clickhandler.t line 6, <GEN7> line 4.
t/03_clickhandler....dubious
        Test returned status 29 (wstat 7424, 0x1d00)
DIED. FAILED tests 1-8
        Failed 8/8 tests, 0.00% okay
Failed Test         Stat Wstat Total Fail  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t/00_basic.t           1   256     1    1  1
t/01_hello.t          26  6656    ??   ??  ??
t/02_hello_sweet.t    19  4864    ??   ??  ??
t/03_clickhandler.t   29  7424     8   16  1-8
Failed 4/4 test scripts. 9/9 subtests failed.
Files=4, Tests=9,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.00 cusr +  0.00 csys =  0.00 CPU)
Failed 4/4 test programs. 9/9 subtests failed.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe' : return code '0x1d'
Stop.
```

From above log, I could see that:

> class Error: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient could not be found.

I have no idea that I missed anything.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Minh.

Comment: Yes, I set JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25" as location I installed JDK. Btw, I can run some Java inline code (with Inline::Java)

Comment: I try to install it, set CLASSPATH to *.jar file in HTMLUnit lib. I write some code and get result "Error:  Class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient not found at C:/Perl/site/lib/Inline/Java.pm line 619".

Comment: If your need is to test Javascript on web pages, try WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript or WWW::Selenium.  Selenium will give you the most realistic results as it uses a real web browser.

Comment: I would like to overcome AJAX and JS issue. I used to play with Selenium, it works well but pretty slow so I try to investigate HTMLUnit to see if it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. 
There's different between path in Unix and Windows system. Unix uses ':' for a delimiter but Windows uses ';'. So what I've done is that open HTMLUnit.pm and change all of ':' to ';'.
With HTMLUnit version 0.15 I made changes at these lines below:
Line 78:

```
return join ';', map { "$jar_path/$_" } qw( # return join ':', map { "$jar_path/$_" } qw(
```

Line 127:

```
$custom_jars = join(';', @{$parameters{'jars'}}); # $custom_jars = join(':', @{$parameters{'jars'}});
```

Line 148:

```
CLASSPATH => collect_default_jars() . ";" . $custom_jars, # CLASSPATH => collect_default_jars() . ":" . $custom_jars,
```

And it works like a magic.

Answer (score 1):

(it wouldn't let me comment on an existing answer)

I see your answer about ':' vs ';'. I'll try to include a fix in the next WWW::HtmlUnit release (I am the author of the perl bindings).